# How to evaluate an improper integral.

Tags: improper-integrals

I don't conceive how to evaluate the improper integral:
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x-1}}dx.
$$

When this converges, I'm glad if you give the value of this integral.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We have:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x+1)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx = \sin(1)\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx+\cos(1)\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx \tag{1}$$
and through a change of variable we get the Fresnel integrals:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}=2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\cos(x^2)\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}},$$
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}=2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(x^2)\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}},\tag{2}$$
hence:
$$ I = \left(\sin(1)+\cos(1)\right)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}.\tag{3} $$

Comment: I haven't known the Fresnel integral. Thank you!

Comment: @P.Mike: [Fresnel integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) are related to the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) by way of [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula).

Comment: @LucianThak you for giving nice information! I'll check later.